# Trying to deobfuscate multi layered javascript

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation, javascript

Can someone deobfuscate this code? I am not getting any way to deobfuscate  this.

Unable to paste it over here as it over passed 30,000 word limit.

http://pastebin.com/V327Q8Hg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly cleaned up, you can rename vars if you will.
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uySNcxuX)

Comment: Hey how did you do this?
I still see some hex values, possible to remove that and get the exact value?

Comment: these are not hex values, these are variable names, i didnt bother renaming stuff manually. Not sure if the script can still be run either. didnt try. I used beautify on it and wrote a python script to replace variables which you can see at the top, i.e. the contents of var _0xe473

Comment: can you tell me which method you used? when I used http://jsbeautifier.org/ it gives some other values in 1st line which is there in your fix.

Comment: add a tickbox for unescape printable chars, should do the trick.